# Why didn't Satyaki fight from Kaurava's Side?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, duryodhana, satyaki

Although Sri Krishna promised to Duryodhan that all his army would fight for him except Krishna himself however Satyaki chose to fight from Pandava's side. I think as he was also Yadav, he should have fought along with Kritvarma.